# JAVA logical operations

Tags: java

I really don't understand this kind of "operations" or what are they called :

```
System.out.println((1<2) ?5: (3<4)   +   "   ");
```

Is the same with this code ?

```
if(1<2)
   return 5;
else if (3<4)
```

But after ':' it says *Dead code* . Why is that ?

Comment: `Dead Code` informs you about code that can't ever be reached. This is the case since 1 will always be smaller than 2. Please read http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018 to learn more about the `ternary operator` (that is what this construct is called)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987213/return-value-syntax-in-java/9987239#9987239

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler evaluates constant expressions at compile time. Because of that, the expression `1<2` is fully equivalent to the expression `true`, making the initial part of your conditional expression look like this:

```
System.out.println((true) ? 5 : (3<4)   +   "   ");
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^
//        Important code          |
//                                |
//        Useless code -----------+
```

The compiler does not stop at evaluating `1<2`, it goes on to evaluating the rest of the expression, which produces `5`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is weird, I really do not understand what are you trying to achieve. I think it is wrong, it should be like this:

```
return 1 < 2 ? 5 : 3 < 4 ? 1 : 2;
```

You can rewrite it into if-else form:

```
if (1 < 2)
    return 5;
if (3 < 4)
    return 1;
return 2;
```

Since return causes the program to jump out of function, else is not needed in this particular example.